# Is it possible to skip an table from Rollback in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, rollback

I am having a scenario where validating the data and inserting the valid data into some of the tables and updating the status into audit table in Oracle package. when there is a validation failure then want to revert all other table data except audit table information. Is it possible to skip rollback for one table. After each table adding status to audit table.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Besides pragma autonomous_transaction, there is also the possibility to set savepoint and rollback to savepoint. Yet the autonomous transaction must be committed or rolled back separately. When using autonomous_transaction you no longer have one transaction, but two or more transactions, while by using savepoint you have one transaction. Still, there is no way to specifically rollback only one table, although such a thing may be achieved by using savepoint and rollback to savepoint.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it is done by a separate **autonomous transaction** procedure which modifies the audit table and commits changes being made.

As it is an autonomous transaction, that `commit` won't affect the main transaction so - once you `rollback` - changes you made in all other tables will be rolled back, but info stored in audit table will remain *as is*.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to skip rollback for one table.

No. When you `ROLLBACK` a transaction, the entire transaction is rolled back and you cannot pick and choose which parts of it are rolled-back or not.

> When there is a validation failure then want to revert all other table data except audit table information.

You need to either:

1. Use multiple transactions and perform the (validated) data modifications in one transaction and the audit data modifications in a separate transaction and then `ROLLBACK` the first transaction and `COMMIT` the second transaction. This is normally done using an `AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION`.
2. Use a single transaction and perform the audit data modifications first, create a `SAVEPOINT` and only then perform the (validated) data modifications and if they fail then `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` to undo all the changes after that save point. You can then choose to `COMMIT` or could still `ROLLBACK` to the previous `COMMIT` before the `SAVEPOINT`.
3. Use a single transaction and perform the audit data modifications first and `COMMIT` them and only then perform the (validated) data modifications and if they fail then `ROLLBACK` to undo all the changes to that last `COMMIT`.